# Need a little bit of help with text alignment in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Hey I am having a bit of a delmma. I can't figure out for the life of me how I would set the position of the text to be a certain width without moving the image too any ideas? http://s72956.gridserver.com/dev/

Comment: Basiclly I need the text to be on one side the images on the other in the content box ( press the calendar button)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to load your sandbox site, but the first thing that comes to mind, is setting the "position" element in your css

```
.text {position: relative; width: 100px;top:0px; left:0px}
.pic {position: relative; width: 100px top: 0px; left: 102px}
```

Again, I can't see your problem, so I'm just throwing this out there.